# Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_16: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I got the error `Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_16: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2` with the following code:

```
#Step 6: Initialize the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

#Step 7: Adding the LSTM layers and some Dropout regularization

#Dropout regularization: drops out unnecessary data, so we are not shifting huge amounts of data through the network

#Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
#units - dimensionality in output space
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))

#Adding the second LSTM layer and some Dropout regulariation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 25, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 12, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 6))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Step 8: Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
```

The dimensions of X_train are `(114, 1, 216)` (produced when I computer `X_train.shape`). Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What data is this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing two values in `input_shape` of first LSTM layer.

Keras `LSTM` takes and input with shape of `(samples, time_steps, nfeatures)` and your layers input has to have this shape.